# How to delete an element from a nested list?

Tags: clojure

I have a deeply nested list and I want to delete a given element from all its occurrences in the list. I have this code:

```
(defn eliminate [value lst]
            (defn sub-eliminate [lst]
              (def currentItem (first lst))
              (if-not (empty? lst)
                (if (seq? currentItem)
                  (cons (sub-eliminate currentItem) (sub-eliminate (rest lst)))
                  (if (= value currentItem)
                    (sub-eliminate (rest lst))
                    (cons currentItem (sub-eliminate (rest lst)))
                    )
                  )
                '()
                )
              )
              (sub-eliminate lst)
            )
```

But, it doesn't delete at inner levels. Why??

Comment: What input is it failing on? I've tried it a couple of times, but I don't see it failing. Please include an example in your question.

Comment: Placing right parentheses by themselves on a line is [considered bad style](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#gather-trailing-parens) (same for all LISPs)

Comment: `def` and `defn` can only create globals, use `let` / `fn` / `letfn` for local bindings, and `atom` / `ref` / `agent` for globals with mutable state

Comment: `(clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (sequential? %) (remove #{value} %) %) form)`

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you're using vectors as sequences.

```
(eliminate 3 [3 3])
;()

(eliminate 3 [3 [3]])
;([3])
```

*This would have been trivial to find had you shown us an example: tut, tut!*

---

*What's going on?*

Although vectors are seqable, they are not sequences:

```
(seq? [])
;false
```

At the outer level, you treat `lst` as a sequence, so `first` and `rest` work, since they wrap their argument in an implicit `seq`. But `seq?` will fail on any immediately enclosed vector, and those further in won't even be seen.

If you replace `seq?` with `sequential?`, lists and vectors will work.

```
(sequential? [])
;true
```

---

More serious, as @noisesmith noted, is your use of `def` and `defn` at inner scope. Replace them with `let` or `letfn`.

You could also improve your style:

1. Replace `(if-not (empty? lst) ... )` with `(if (seq lst) ...)`.
2. Use `cond` to flatten your nested `if`s. This requires inverting 
   the test in (1), so removes the need for it.
3. Use `recur` for the tail-recursive case where you find `value`, as
   [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26180203/1562315) does.

If you don't want to see the result, look away now:

```
(defn eliminate [value lst]
  (letfn [(sub-eliminate [lst]
            (let [current-item (first lst)]
              (cond
               (empty? lst) '()
               (sequential? current-item) (cons (sub-eliminate current-item) 
                                                (sub-eliminate (rest lst)))
               (= value current-item) (recur (rest lst))
               :else (cons current-item (sub-eliminate (rest lst))))))]
    (sub-eliminate lst)))
```

There is a remaining tender spot:

- You invoke `(first lst)` before you know that `lst` is not empty. No
  harm done: you'll just get `nil`, which you ignore.

---

*An Alternative Apporach using Destructuring*

You can often use [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--Binding%20Forms%20(Destructuring)) to abbreviate recursive processing of sequences. I'd be inclined to express your function thus:

```
(defn eliminate [x xs]
  ((fn rem-x [xs]
     (if-let [[y & ys] (seq xs)]
       (if (= x y)
         (recur ys)
         (cons
          (if (sequential? y) (rem-x y) y)
          (rem-x ys)))
       ()))
   xs))
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of learning take a look at this function:

```
(define rember*
  (lambda (x l)
    (cond ((null? l) '())
          ((atom? (car l))
          (if (eq? (car l) x)
              (rember* x (cdr l))
              (cons (car l)
                    (rember* x (cdr l)))))
          (else (cons (rember* x (car l))
                      (rember* x (cdr l)))))))
```

This is a simple recursive function from book 'The Little Schemer', which is a good source to learn how to write such recursive functions.

Let's see if we can translate it into Clojure:

```
(defn rember* [x l]
  (cond (empty? l) '()
        (seq? (first l)) (cons (rember* x (first l))
                               (rember* x (rest l)))
        :else (if (= (first l) x)
                (recur x (rest l))
                (cons (first l)
                      (rember* x (rest l))))))
```

```
user> (rember* 'x '((x y) x (z (((((x))))))))
;; => ((y) (z ((((()))))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn expel [victim xs] 
  (mapcat (fn [x]
            (cond
              (sequential? x) [(expel victim x)]
              (= x victim) [] 
              :else [x])) 
          xs))
```

Comment: +1 Good solution, although I would give it another name.

Comment: @Mark Thanks. I took your advice on using a different name.